# Windows COM: generic byte array sink

Tags: windows, com

Is there a common (standard) Windows COM interface that defines a generic byte array sink (i.e. that defines something like a `write(char* buf, int len)` method)?

I could define a custom interface and implement it, but I think there must be some generic COM interface already defined for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to IStream or ISequentialStream. For the methods you don't want to implement, just return E_NOTIMPL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380014(v=vs.85).aspx